# Save with update_fields did not affect any rows (while changing class)

Tags: django, inheritance

Let's have a model with decorator:

```
def upgradable(model):
  @classmethod
  def upgrade(cls, base, **kwargs):
    base.__class__ = cls
    for attr, value in kwargs.items():
      setattr(base, attr, value)
    return base
  setattr(model, "upgrade", upgrade)
  return model

class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.name.upper()
    super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and inherited model:

```
@upgradable
class User(Person):
  email = models.EmailField();
```

and I'm trying to upgrade

```
person = Person.objects.get(...)
user = User.upgrade(person, email="example@example.com")
user.save()
```

But the error appears:

```
Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.
```

in connection to `super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` (in method save of model person)

It isn't total wrong, because indeed I don't want to change anything in table person, I just want to add something to table user (pointer to person and email).

So how to skip this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer wasn't obvious - I tried to add

```
user.save(force_update = True)
```

but it isn't work.

But

```
user.save(force_insert = True)
```

do the job. Strange, but works.